# how can i work with a lot data .push() for use it outside of .map()?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, array.prototype.map

In this moment i have a problem. How can i push a lot of data for work with it outside of .map().

I need push a lot of data in `const todo = []` and see data outside of .map() `codigoP.map`

i tried with `.promise` but i don't know how implement when one work in a push of lot data like this:

```
const todo = [];
let dateNow = moment();
let diferencia = 0;

codigoP.map(async (item)=> {
  const listaPrecio = await models.listas_precios.findOne({
    where: {
      producto_id: item.id,
      cliente_id: empresa.id
    }
  });
  let precioIva = 0;
  if (listaPrecio) {
    precioIva = listaPrecio.iva;
  }
  cant += parseInt(detDevolucion.cantidadProducto);
  precioTotal = detDevolucion.precio_producto * parseInt(detDevolucion.cantidadProducto);
  const totalIva =  precioTotal + precioIva;
  total += totalIva;
  totalConIva += precioTotal;
  ivaTotal += precioIva;
  let fechaVencimiento = moment(item.fechaVencimiento).utc().toDate();
  diferencia = dateNow.diff(fechaVencimiento, 'days');
  todo.push({
    codigo: item.codigo,
    nombre: item.nombre,
    vidaUtil: diferencia,
    lote: detDevolucion.lote_id,
    cantidad: detDevolucion.cantidadProducto,
    precio: numeral(detDevolucion.precio_producto).format('$0,0.00'),
    precioTotal: numeral(precioTotal).format('$0,0.00'),
    iva: numeral(precioIva).format('$0,0.00'),
    totalIva: numeral(totalIva).format('$0,0.00'),
    observacion: detDevolucion.observacion,
    fechaVenc: dateFormat(item.fechaVencimiento, "yyyy-mm-dd")
  });
  console.log('todo: ', todo);// **this works, return the values**
  diferencia = 0;
});
  console.log('todo: ', todo); //**this return todo [], empty array, this is my problem.**
```

Comment: could you please create a working jsfiddle with the issue you are facing?

Comment: from the looks of it you're using async to push to `todo`. You're console logging `todo` directly after the code block, but not using a promise to wait for the async function to complete its job. This means that `todo` is showing as empty because it is empty at the time you're logging it to the screen.

Comment: @SnehalShah [jsfiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/JimmySorza/jyh5oxv2/) line 183, it is a file of loopback

Comment: you are using map wrongly. Map returns a new array of the mapped items.
Perhaps you want a forEach and do the logic inside of it as you are doing async stuff.

Comment: @zfrisch  i writed `const todo = codigoP.map(async (item)=> {` at the start and `return Promise.resolve(todo)` at final but it return `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: Read about Promise.All() [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all)

Comment: @Andy the problem is that my company doesn't allow use foreach in this. i can use _lodash but i don't know how implement it.

Comment: I am not quite understanding why you would need to do a push then map over the same array. Whatever you want to do in the map function can be handled in the push directly. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SnehalShah i guess so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, as we've discussed above. Map returns a new array and return the object for each iteration.

Edit: you can try using Promise.all to resolve the promises before returning.

```
let dateNow = moment();
let diferencia = 0;
const todo = await Promise.all(codigoP.map(async (item)=> {
  const listaPrecio = models.listas_precios.findOne({
    where: {
      producto_id: item.id,
      cliente_id: empresa.id
    }
  });
  let precioIva = 0;
  if (listaPrecio) {
    precioIva = listaPrecio.iva;
  }
  cant += parseInt(detDevolucion.cantidadProducto);
  precioTotal = detDevolucion.precio_producto * parseInt(detDevolucion.cantidadProducto);
  const totalIva =  precioTotal + precioIva;
  total += totalIva;
  totalConIva += precioTotal;
  ivaTotal += precioIva;
  let fechaVencimiento = moment(item.fechaVencimiento).utc().toDate();
  diferencia = dateNow.diff(fechaVencimiento, 'days');
  return {
    codigo: item.codigo,
    nombre: item.nombre,
    vidaUtil: diferencia,
    lote: detDevolucion.lote_id,
    cantidad: detDevolucion.cantidadProducto,
    precio: numeral(detDevolucion.precio_producto).format('$0,0.00'),
    precioTotal: numeral(precioTotal).format('$0,0.00'),
    iva: numeral(precioIva).format('$0,0.00'),
    totalIva: numeral(totalIva).format('$0,0.00'),
    observacion: detDevolucion.observacion,
    fechaVenc: dateFormat(item.fechaVencimiento, "yyyy-mm-dd")
  };
  //console.log('todo: ', todo);// **this works, return the values**
  //diferencia = 0;
}));
  console.log('todo: ', todo);
```

Comment: Thank you Andy, i will implement it and i will tell you.

Comment: Andy, this print me in console: `todo:  [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]
`

Comment: promises will return pending if they have not been resolved yet.
you can do somthing like  todo[0].then(....).catch(....); to resolve your promise.

Comment: see edited post. You need to resolve the promises, either before returning it or after returning it.
You can use Promise.all(), or you can use instead map, the async.map method.
Without beeing able to execute your code, makes it a bit difficult to debug it for you.

Comment: i did another change, please look. you can resolve the promises after too. I think second edit will work best for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167768/discussion-between-jimmy-sorza-and-andy).